# Show HTML elements based on array value

Tags: javascript

I have a series of checkboxes that can accept multiple "checks." What I want to have is have a div shown for every checkbox checked.

I have it set up to capture the value of every checkbox and store it in an array. But now I'm trying to figure out how to display each element for every case, e.g., If A is selected, show A; if A and B are selected, show A & B, etc.

I started doing this as a series of if...then statements, but I feel like that will quickly become unwieldily. Then I thought about using "switch" but couldn't get that to work. Anyone have any thoughts?

```js
function GetSelected() {
  var selected = new Array();
  var tblFruits = document.getElementById("tblFruits");
  var chks = tblFruits.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
    if (chks[i].checked) {
        selected.push(chks[i].value);
    }
  }
  
  if (selected.includes("1")) {
    document.getElementById("mango").style.display = "block";
    }
  else if (selected.includes("1") && selected.includes("2")) {
      document.getElementById("mango").style.display = "block" ;
      document.getElementById("apple").style.display = "block" ;
    }
  else {
    console.log("Oops"); 
  }        
  console.log(selected.includes("2"));
}
```

```css
#mango, #apple, #banana, #guava, #orange {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblFruits">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkMango" type="checkbox" value="1"/><label for="chkMango">Mango</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkApple" type="checkbox" value="2"/><label for="chkApple">Apple</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkBanana" type="checkbox" value="3"/><label for="chkBanana">Banana</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkGuava" type="checkbox" value="4"/><label for="chkGuava">Guava</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkOrange" type="checkbox" value="5"/><label for="chkOrange">Orange</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type = "button" value = "Get" onclick = "GetSelected()" />

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="mango">Mango</div>
  <div id="apple">Apple</div>
  <div id="banana">Banana</div>
  <div id="guava">Guava</div>
  <div id="orange">Orange</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try [`React`](https://reactjs.org/) for such tasks.

Comment: can you convert your code to snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over complicating this. There is a one to one relationship between the checkboxes and the content elements.

Just loop over the checkboxes and parse their id to get the associated content id and within that loop update the display of the associated content element every iteration.

Or do the reverse , loop over the content elements and see if the associated checkbox is checked.

You could make it even simpler by setting the values as the content id and skip a line of parsing the checkbox id.  Then the content id would be `el.value`

```js
function GetSelected() {

  document.querySelectorAll('#tblFruits input').forEach((el) => {
    const contentId = el.id.replace('chk', '').toLowerCase()
    document.getElementById(contentId).style.display = el.checked ? 'block' : 'none';   
  });

}
```

```css
#mango,
#apple,
#banana,
#guava,
#orange {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblFruits">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkMango" type="checkbox" value="1" /><label for="chkMango">Mango</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkApple" type="checkbox" value="2" /><label for="chkApple">Apple</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkBanana" type="checkbox" value="3" /><label for="chkBanana">Banana</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkGuava" type="checkbox" value="4" /><label for="chkGuava">Guava</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkOrange" type="checkbox" value="5" /><label for="chkOrange">Orange</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Get" onclick="GetSelected()" />

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="mango">Mango</div>
  <div id="apple">Apple</div>
  <div id="banana">Banana</div>
  <div id="guava">Guava</div>
  <div id="orange">Orange</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Simple as!

Answer (score 1):

In your solution selected array contains entire htmlElement and not just value of the checkbox, but you are treating array as in it contains only value.
This will solve your problem

```js
function clearSelection() {
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > div');
    [...divs].forEach(div => {
      div.style.display = 'none';
    });
}

function GetSelected() {
clearSelection()
        var tblFruits = document.getElementById("tblFruits");
        var chks = tblFruits.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        
        const selected = Array.prototype.filter.call(chks, checkbox => checkbox.checked).map(data => data.id);
        

selected.forEach(id => {
  var resultId = id.slice(3).toLowerCase();

document.getElementById(resultId).style.display = 'block';
})               
        
    }
```

```css
#mango, #apple, #banana, #guava, #orange {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<table id="tblFruits">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkMango" type="checkbox" value="1"/><label for="chkMango">Mango</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkApple" type="checkbox" value="2"/><label for="chkApple">Apple</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkBanana" type="checkbox" value="3"/><label for="chkBanana">Banana</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkGuava" type="checkbox" value="4"/><label for="chkGuava">Guava</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkOrange" type="checkbox" value="5"/><label for="chkOrange">Orange</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type = "button" value = "Get" onclick = "GetSelected()" />

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="mango">Mango</div>
    <div id="apple">Apple</div>
    <div id="banana">Banana</div>
    <div id="guava">Guava</div>
    <div id="orange">Orange</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

checkbox value and fruits div having relation. If checkbox banana is checked then `div` with id `banana` will get displyed and other div style will set to `display:none`.

```
    <table id="tblFruits">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkMango" type="checkbox" value="mango"/><label for="chkMango">Mango</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkApple" type="checkbox" value="apple"/><label for="chkApple">Apple</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkBanana" type="checkbox" value="banana"/><label for="chkBanana">Banana</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkGuava" type="checkbox" value="guava"/><label for="chkGuava">Guava</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkOrange" type="checkbox" value="orange"/><label for="chkOrange">Orange</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type = "button" value = "Get" onclick = "GetSelected()" />

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="mango">Mango</div>
    <div id="apple">Apple</div>
    <div id="banana">Banana</div>
    <div id="guava">Guava</div>
    <div id="orange">Orange</div>
</div>

     function GetSelected() {
        var selected = new Array();
        var tblFruits = document.getElementById("tblFruits");
        var chks = tblFruits.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        // this for loop will check checkbox current value and will hide fruits divs
        for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
            if (chks[i].checked) {
                selected.push(chks[i].value); 
                document.getElementById(chks[i].value).style.display = "block";
            } else {
               document.getElementById(chks[i].value).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        console.log(selected); // All selected fruit stored in this array will diaplyed on console
    }
```

Here is working demo https://playcode.io/657247/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoiding situations in which you hard-code multiple conditions-- it scales very poorly.  Instead, I would find a way to link each checkbox to an option and simply loop the results.  In the below, we get the associated text label and use it to find the matched div by `id` to show it:

```js
function GetSelected() {
    var selected = new Array();
    var tblFruits = document.getElementById("tblFruits");
    var chks = tblFruits.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

    // clear all previously shown options
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > div');
    [...divs].forEach(div => {
      div.style.display = 'none';
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (chks[i].checked) {
            let value = chks[i].value;
            let text = chks[i].labels[0].textContent.toLowerCase();;
            selected.push(value);
            document.querySelector(`#${text}`).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    
    // do anything else you need with the checkbox array
}
```

```css
#mango, #apple, #banana, #guava, #orange {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblFruits">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkMango" type="checkbox" value="1"/><label for="chkMango">Mango</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkApple" type="checkbox" value="2"/><label for="chkApple">Apple</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkBanana" type="checkbox" value="3"/><label for="chkBanana">Banana</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkGuava" type="checkbox" value="4"/><label for="chkGuava">Guava</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkOrange" type="checkbox" value="5"/><label for="chkOrange">Orange</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type = "button" value = "Get" onclick = "GetSelected()" />

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="mango">Mango</div>
    <div id="apple">Apple</div>
    <div id="banana">Banana</div>
    <div id="guava">Guava</div>
    <div id="orange">Orange</div>
</div>
```

This solution attempted to not touch/change any of the markup.  It's *super* flimsy as is-- all you need is for the label to have a space and it falls apart.  Instead, consider using `data-` attributes to provide more concrete links between the two pieces of markup that can be used to connect them and make changes as need in a manner that is derived.